# Is it better to run Cron every minute or write Cron Job dynamically?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a simple application where users can add a post and schedule it to go live at a certain time.

Now I have two approaches before me:

**First Approach:** 
I can set a script which will be called every minute and it will check if any posts are pending at the current time and will publish them if they are like so:

My Cron Job:

```
1 * * * * php myScriptToMakePostLive.php
```

or

**Second Approach**
I can set cron jobs dynamically on server at the time when user submits his post to publish later. I am using this script:

```
 public function schedulePost(){
        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $_POST['body'];
        $post->save();

        $scheduledTime = Carbon::parse($_POST['publish_on']);

        //saving cron dynamically 
        $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
        file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.PHP_EOL."{$scheduledTime->minute} {$scheduledTime->hour} {$scheduledTime->day} {$scheduledTime->month} * php myScriptToMakePostLive {$post->id}".PHP_EOL);
        echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
        die('Your post has been Scheduled !!');

    }
```

What I want to know is which is the better approach and why?

Comment: Does this need to work on shared hosting, or can you install new software, like job queues?

Comment: 1 * * * * is every hour at 1 minutes, every minutes is * * * * *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, to be honest, neither.

I'd use a scheduling service like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). And if I absolutely had to roll my own scheduling service, it'd be with [`at`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)) and not `cron`

It also depends on how often you think users will have posts scheduled. I doubt it's all that often.

Comment: Out of interest, what's PHP library support like for Celery?

Comment: Uh, I found a guy on github with a library, but I've never used it myself: https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php

Comment: Well, it's got a lot of stars, so that's a good start `:-)`. I've asked the OP whether they are in a position to install other software - they might be on shared hosting. I wonder if a job queue might be too substantial a tool when cron/at would do fine - with a minor delay, admittedly.

Comment: Hum. I'd think they'd have access to `at`, at the very least, if they have access to `cron`. I'm just not a fan of `cron-every-minute` unless it's actually justified. (One of my friends managed to cause massive slowdowns on a shared server by cron-every-minute django. We finagled something with cron setting at jobs. This was, uh, before I knew about celery)

Comment: I use cron for a minute heartbeat on Ubuntu LTS 14.04, and the load is so negligible it approaches zero, for me at least. I agree it feels like it _ought_ to be wasteful, but I've not found so in practice, and there's something to be said for using software on the box already.

Comment: What's the advantage of `at` over `cron`, btw?

Comment: Not running a script every minute, which means not bringing down the server, which means not getting IT angry at me. :P But, no, `at` is meant for scheduling. (I also used it to set reminders for myself via irc :P)

Comment: I don't follow. If I want to make a check every minute to see if a database value has changed, how is `at` an improvement? It still needs to call something every minute.

Comment: Well, if you *have* to check every minute, there's no way around it. But with at, you can take an input and schedule a script to deal with the input, say, N hours down the line. Useful when these inputs come in only a few dozen times per day and don't schedule output events nearly every minute.

Comment: Ah, you _programmatically_ schedule something? That's cool, yes - like a poor dev's queue. Cron might be able to do that by editing crontab files under the web server's user account, but it'd be rather messy. (I'll stick with my lazy minute heartbeat for now ;-).

Comment: You probably weren't also looking up a database and possibly sending emails every minute on a computer that had seen its days and was also the generalized "mess around with code" computer for a college campus. So. Uh :P

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for the first approach because it is much simpler.  You only have one moving part (the single cron job) rather than adding a new job per scheduled post.  You also run the risk in option #2 of having 2 processes trying to write the crontab at the same time and potentially losing one of the jobs.  #1 is simple and straightforward, and I don't see what #2 really buys you.

Comment: in the first approach i have a script which will run every minute just to check if i have any posts pending at current time. I was worried if this may cause performance issues.

Comment: I use that exact approach on a site with hundreds of thousands of articles and 15m monthly visitors.  As long as your table is properly indexed, it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd use the "static cronjob" approach and store jobs on a database because of some shortcomings of "cron as a dynamic oneoff scheduler":

- That crontab will get big... The croned job should remove itself from the crontab on running?
- What if your server has downtime when it should be dispatching a job? Does crontab check for overdue jobs?
- If you need to move your application to another server you'll need to migrate the crontab... seems weird but maybe it's not **that** weird.
- Running shell commands containing user input needs **a lot** of caution.